# Wix Installer: Changing the installation path for an existing app does nothing

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wix, windows-installer

I have one application installed
When I run the application.exe again, and select the "Change" option
And specify a different installation path, Wizard completes, no errors. But the new specified folder contains nothing and the previous installation folder contains all files.
I was expecting the files should move from previous installation folder to the new one. Which is not happening.

#Bundle.wxs:

```
<!--The following WixVariable are used in mbapreq (a built-in Managed Bootstrapper Prerequisite UI).
If managed bootstrapper failed to start, it would try to launch mbapreq.
mbapreq would only install the package id which is specified by WixMbaPrereqPackageId, and the PackageId should exist in chain. -->
<WixVariable Id="WixMbaPrereqPackageId" Value="Netfx462Full" />
<WixVariable Id="WixMbaPrereqLicenseUrl" Value="NetfxLicense.rtf" />
<WixVariable Id="PreqbaLogo" Value="$(var.PreqbaLogoPath)" />

<!--UI String Files-->
<Variable Name="UIStringFiles" Type="string" Value="WixUI.wxl;$(var.StringsWxl)"/>

<BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="ManagedBootstrapperApplicationHost" >
  <Payload SourceFile="$(var.OutputPath)\InstallerBootstrapperUI.dll"/>
  <Payload SourceFile="$(var.OutputPath)\ConnectorBootstrapperUI.dll"/>
  <Payload SourceFile="$(var.OutputPath)\BootstrapperCore.dll"/>
  <Payload SourceFile="$(var.OutputPath)\BootstrapperCore.config" />
  <Payload SourceFile="$(var.OutputPath)\Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.dll" />
  <Payload SourceFile="$(var.WindowsPatchDirectory)\Windows6.1-KB2999226-x64.msu" />
  <Payload SourceFile="$(var.WindowsPatchDirectory)\Windows8.1-KB2999226-x64.msu" />
  <Payload SourceFile="$(var.WindowsPatchDirectory)\Windows8-RT-KB2999226-x64.msu" />
  <Payload SourceFile="WixUI.wxl" />
  <Payload SourceFile="$(var.StringsWxl)" />
</BootstrapperApplicationRef>

<Variable Name="MainPackageId" Type="string" Value="connector" />
<Variable Name="LaunchConfig" Type="numeric" Value="1" Persisted="yes" />
<Variable Name="LaunchConfigExecutable" Type="string" Value="[InstallFolder]/ProxyUI.exe" />
<Variable Name="LaunchConfigParam" Type="string" Value="/setup"/>
<Variable Name="LaunchConfigParamRepair" Type="string" Value="/setup"/>
<Variable Name="LaunchConfigElevated" Type="numeric" Value="1" />
<Variable Name="InstallFolder" Type="string" Value="[ProgramFiles64Folder][DIR_PROG_COMPANY]\[DIR_PROG_PRODUCT]" Persisted="yes"/>
<Variable Name="DisplayProductName" Type="string" Value="[PRODUCT_NAME]"/>
<Variable Name="DisplayBrandProductName" Type="string" Value="[BRAND_PRODUCT_NAME]"/>
<Variable Name="DisplayProductVersion" Type="string" Value="!(bind.packageVersion.connector)"/>
<Variable Name="InstallFolderRegistrySearchKey" Type="string" Value="$(var.RegistryKey)" />
<Variable Name="InstallFolderRegistrySearchValue" Type="string" Value="(Default)" /> 
<Variable Name="IcoPath" Type="string" Value="$(var.IcoPath)" Persisted="yes" />
<Variable Name="ProductName" Type="string" Value="$(var.ProductName)" Persisted="yes" />
<Variable Name="InstallPackageErrorKB2999226_Windows81_x64" Type="string" Value="!(loc.INSTALL_KB2999226_ERROR)" Persisted="yes" />
<Variable Name="InstallPackageErrorKB2999226_Windows8_x64" Type="string" Value="!(loc.INSTALL_KB2999226_ERROR)" Persisted="yes" />
<Variable Name="InstallPackageErrorKB2999226_Windows61_x64" Type="string" Value="!(loc.INSTALL_KB2999226_ERROR)" Persisted="yes" />
<Variable Name="InstallPackageErrorNetfx462Full" Type="string" Value="!(loc.INSTALL_DOTNET_4_6_2_ERROR)" Persisted="yes" />
<Variable Name="InstallingPackageKB2999226_Windows81_x64" Type="string" Value="!(loc.INSTALL_KB2999226)" Persisted="yes" />
<Variable Name="InstallingPackageKB2999226_Windows8_x64" Type="string" Value="!(loc.INSTALL_KB2999226)" Persisted="yes" />
<Variable Name="InstallingPackageKB2999226_Windows61_x64" Type="string" Value="!(loc.INSTALL_KB2999226)" Persisted="yes" /> 
<Variable Name="InstallingPackageNetfx462Full" Type="string" Value="!(loc.INSTALL_DOTNET_4_6_2)" Persisted="yes" />

<util:RegistrySearch Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full" Value="Release" Variable="Netfx4FullVersion" />
<util:RegistrySearch Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full" Value="Release" Variable="Netfx4x64FullVersion" Win64="yes" />
<util:RegistrySearch Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Component Based Servicing\Packages\Package_for_KB2919355~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.3.1.14" Value="CurrentState" Variable="KB2919355Installed" Win64="yes" />
<util:FileSearch Id="WindowsUCRTVersion" Path="[SystemFolder]\api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll" Variable="WindowsUCRTVersion" Result="version" />
<util:FileSearch Id="WindowsUCRTVersionExists" Path="[SystemFolder]\api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll" Variable="WindowsUCRTVersionExists" Result="exists" />

<bal:Condition Message="Setup cannot continue because Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 or above is required to install the $(var.ProductName)">
    <![CDATA[VersionNT64 > v6.1 OR (VersionNT64 = v6.1 AND ServicePackLevel >= 1)]]>
</bal:Condition>

<bal:Condition Message="The update corresponding to KB2919355 needs to be installed before you can install this product on Windows Server 2012 R2">
    <![CDATA[VersionNT64 <> v6.3 OR (VersionNT64 = v6.3 AND KB2919355Installed = 112)]]>
</bal:Condition>
<Chain>
  
  <!-- Seems we cannot install .NET 4.6.2 using the installer if the NetFx4 is disabled. Alternatively, we can use dism. -->
  <ExePackage
      Id="EnableNetFx4"
      SourceFile="run.cmd"
      Compressed="yes"
      PerMachine="yes"
      DisplayName="!(loc.ENABLE_DOTNET_4_FEATURES)"
      LogPathVariable="EnableNetFx4Log"
      Permanent="yes"
      InstallCommand="[WindowsFolder]sysnative\dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFx4 /all &gt; [TempFolder]dism_netfx4_command.txt"
      DetectCondition="Netfx4FullVersion AND (NOT VersionNT64 OR Netfx4x64FullVersion)"
      InstallCondition="VersionNT &gt;= v6.2"
      bal:PrereqSupportPackage="yes"
      />
      
  <!-- For Windows Server 2012 R2 -->
  <MsuPackage
    Id="KB2999226_Windows81_x64"
    SourceFile="$(var.WindowsPatchDirectory)\Windows8.1-KB2999226-x64.msu"
    InstallSize="970803"
    Permanent="yes"
    Vital="yes"
    DisplayName="!(loc.INSTALL_KB2999226)"
    InstallCondition="VersionNT = v6.3 AND VersionNT64"
    DetectCondition="WindowsUCRTVersionExists AND WindowsUCRTVersion &gt;= v10.0.10137.0"
    bal:PrereqSupportPackage="yes"
    KB="2999226">
  </MsuPackage>
  
  <!-- For Windows Server 2012 -->
  <MsuPackage
    Id="KB2999226_Windows8_x64"
    SourceFile="$(var.WindowsPatchDirectory)\Windows8-RT-KB2999226-x64.msu"
    InstallSize="1362211"
    Permanent="yes"
    Vital="yes" 
    DisplayName="!(loc.INSTALL_KB2999226)"
    InstallCondition="VersionNT = v6.2 AND VersionNT64"
    DetectCondition="WindowsUCRTVersionExists AND WindowsUCRTVersion &gt;= v10.0.10137.0"
    bal:PrereqSupportPackage="yes"
    KB="2999226">
  </MsuPackage>
  
  <!-- For Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1-->
  <MsuPackage
    Id="KB2999226_Windows61_x64"
    SourceFile="$(var.WindowsPatchDirectory)\Windows6.1-KB2999226-x64.msu"
    InstallSize="1012025"
    Permanent="yes"
    Vital="yes"
    DisplayName="!(loc.INSTALL_KB2999226)"
    InstallCondition="VersionNT = v6.1 AND VersionNT64"
    DetectCondition="WindowsUCRTVersionExists AND WindowsUCRTVersion &gt;= v10.0.10137.0"
    bal:PrereqSupportPackage="yes"
    KB="2999226">
  </MsuPackage>

  <ExePackage
      Id="Netfx462Full"
      InstallCommand="/q /norestart /ChainingPackage &quot;[WixBundleName]&quot; /log &quot;[NetFx462FullLog].html&quot;"
      RepairCommand="/q /norestart /repair /ChainingPackage &quot;[WixBundleName]&quot; /log &quot;[NetFx462FullLog].html&quot;"
      UninstallCommand="/uninstall /q /norestart /ChainingPackage &quot;[WixBundleName]&quot; /log &quot;[NetFx462FullLog].html&quot;"
      PerMachine="yes"
      DetectCondition="Netfx4FullVersion &gt;= 394802 AND (NOT VersionNT64 OR Netfx4x64FullVersion &gt;= 394802)"
      DisplayName="!(loc.INSTALL_DOTNET_4_6_2)"
      Vital="yes"
      Permanent="yes"
      LogPathVariable="NetFx462FullLog"
      Compressed="yes"
      Protocol="netfx4"
      SourceFile="$(var.DotNetPackage)"
      bal:PrereqSupportPackage="yes">
      <ExitCode Behavior="forceReboot" Value="1641" />
      <ExitCode Behavior="forceReboot" Value="3010" />
      <!-- MSI may return 0x80070bc2, However value is stored as signed. 
           So 0x80070bc2 value is -2147021886 -->
      <ExitCode Behavior="forceReboot" Value="-2147021886" />
      <ExitCode Behavior="success" Value="0" />
      <ExitCode Behavior="error"/>
  </ExePackage>

  <MsiPackage
      Id="connector"
      SourceFile="$(var.OutputPath)\$(var.CultureGroupOutputFolder)\installer.msi"
      Compressed="yes"
      EnableFeatureSelection="yes"
      Vital="yes">
    <MsiProperty Name="INSTALLDIR" Value="[InstallFolder]" />
    <MsiProperty Name="ONPREM" Value="$(var.OnPrem)" />
  </MsiPackage>
  
</Chain>
```

Please check the below details and provide your valuable suggestions. Thanks a lot!

Regards,
Kishore

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, the Windows Installer does not let you change the installation directory of Components via maintenance mode or repair. This simply isn't supported by MSI.